# "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ';'" laravel 5.5 in xampp 7.2.2 / PHP 7.2.2

Tags: php, laravel, php-7.2

why am I getting this error while getting data from database in my controller? I use laravel 5.5 and php 7.2.2.

```
public function create()
{
    $categories = Category::all();

    return view('post.create'), compact('categories'); 
}
```

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ';'" in return view('post.create'), compact('categories');

pls help me i dont know why got this error.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function create()
{
    $categories = Category::all();

    return view('post.create', compact('categories')); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've closed `)` too early. The correct syntax is:

```
return view('post.create', compact('categories'));
```

Comment: and your's have no right closing brace.  sorry @Alexey

Comment: @ShobiPP thanks. Fixed. )